# How to disable overlay of jQuery simple modal popup plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, simplemodal

I am using plugin  [simple modal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/) for  showing popup in my site . I need to disable the overlay shown along with popup.  is there any workaround ?Any help would be appreciated thanks

Comment: why do you use this plugin if you need not overlay, why not just use html/css

Comment: If you don't have option to disable it, then you can add code that remove it after you call that plugin. Check what id or class overlay have (in Inspector) and do `$('.<overlay class>').remove();`. You can also edit the plugin and remove the overlay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try -

```
$('#simplemodal-overlay').hide();
```

Answer (score 5):

Add this in you css. It will hide the overlay

```
#simplemodal-overlay{
   display: none !important;
}
```

To make sure it will always work add `overlayId` to `simplemodal-overlay` for all simplemodals you have in your site. like

```
$("#element-id").modal({
    overlayId : 'simplemodal-overlay'
});
```

Then overlay's id will always be `simplemodal-overlay` and the above css will work for all.

Comment: your solution is very good , but I  manged it with jQuery,thats why I marked it as my answer.thanks a lot  for the help

Answer (score 2):

Edited:

```
// Change overlay color and opacity
$("#sample").modal({
opacity:0,
overlayCss: {backgroundColor:"#fff"}
});
```

**Extracted from:** http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/

OR

**See Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/CzPQG/

```
$('#basic-modal .basic').click(function (e) {
    $('#basic-modal-content').modal();        
    $('#simplemodal-overlay').css('display','none'); /* Overlay Div's display = none */
    return false;
});
```

**See Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/Q2LHW/

Comment: @Ahsan thanks for the answer . But in my case user needs to  interact with  the site even if pop up is there.

Comment: User can interact with second Demo if `$('#simplemodal-overlay').css('display','none');`

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the overlay will kill the purpose of using a modal window/dialog. Anyway, you can set the opacity option to 0.

Comment: The is debatable at best. In our project we have several scenarios in which we want a dialog (not a modal dialog) leaving the page behind it active to allow users to interact with it. Setting opacity to 0 would not let you do that.

Comment: then use jquery's dialog which has option to set modal to true or false

Comment: Yes, jQuery dialog has options pre-configured but css fixes it here too. I assume it is prudent to try and achieve with a given technology what you can before telling the rest of your company that you want to change technology because you need to write custom css using this one. Who knows, maybe there was a requirement for using the current technology which jQuery dialog could not fullfill. Changing technology is not always the best  nor should it be a hasty descition.